# Как добавить HTML/CSS/JavaScript файлы в эклипс проект

Tags: javascript, java, html, eclipse

Html/Css/JavaScript проект написан на Sublime Text , то есть находится в отдельной папки..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо добавить эту отдельную папку в эклипс проект , где и в какие папки или под папки такое добавляется ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке добавить таким образом получаю код 404 от браузера. 
Создан War file из такого проекта и задеплоин в томкат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]